# reliability of Button "disableOnClick" in Vaadin 14

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

I'm using Vaadin 14 and to avoid sending requests multiple times when a user double-clicks a button instead of just once, I'm calling `setDisableOnClick(true)` on the `Button` instance.

For some buttons this is not enough: the button can be still clicked multiple times.  When inspecting the dom in Chrome devtools, I can see that the `disableonclick` property is set for these buttons:

[image]

I suspect it's an issue with the order in which event handlers are called (the one to disable should be called before the one to send the request).

I'd rather not set a Boolean on the server side to check whether the action has been performed.  Is there another option to reliably disable the button immediately after clicking?

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a Vaadin bug.  The cases where it doesn't work are when the buttons are in a `Dialog` that gets closed and then reopened.  When you call `setDisableOnClick(true)`, they're using a hack to add the event listener from the server side:

```
/**
 * Initialize client side disabling so disabled if immediate on click even
 * if server-side handling takes some time.
 */
private void initDisableOnClick() {
    if (!disableOnClickConfigured) {
        getElement().executeJs("var disableEvent = function () {"
                + "if($0.getAttribute('disableOnClick')){"
                + " $0.setAttribute('disabled', 'true');" + "}" + "};"
                + "$0.addEventListener('click', disableEvent)");
        disableOnClickConfigured = true;
    }
}
```

When the button is detached and re-attached, this event handler is gone.

Unfortunately calling `setDisableOnClick(true)` again after re-opening the dialog won't help, since `disableOnClickConfigured` will already be set to true so this code will be skipped.

I see three options:

1. When the button gets re-attached (dialog gets reopened), reset private field `disableOnClickConfigured` to `false` through reflection and then call `setDisableOnClick(true)` again.
2. Copy the code to add the client-side event listener and execute it when the button gets re-attached.
3. Avoid the problem by replacing the button with a new one or even create whole a new `Dialog` instance each time it is opened.

It's the last option I chose to go with.  The `Dialog` was a Spring bean so I'm using Prototype scope and inject it with an `ObjectFactory`, then get a new instance before calling `open`.

Comment: Would be really awesome if you could open an issue for this in GitHub, unless one already exists.

Comment: This seems to be the related Vaadin Button issue:
https://github.com/vaadin/flow-components/issues/1401

Comment: @JohannesTuikkala Indeed I created it afterwards, thanks for linking.